# "Rnd" function doesn't work without full menus or navigation pane

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have created an Access database using Access 2007 where the user gets a start-up form that loads a random image from a folder.

I used a very simple way to do it. I generate a random number between 1 and 7 using the "RND" function and and then a nested if to load a corresponding image from the folder.

I also tried a mildly different way to do it by storing numbers in a table 1-7 and select a random record from that (also using the RND function) then using the nested if again.

Both techniques work fine when running the database in full development mode (all menus, ribbons and views are enabled).

The problem is when I try to create a version for the user by disabling both "Allow Full Menus" and "Display Navigation Pane". I get the same image every time. I added a MsgBox to see the value of the generated number and the function mysteriously returns a specific number every time. The same number is generated with every run of the DB.

The first technique I used:

myrand = Int((7 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)

the second technique I used:

select top 1 picid from picslist order by rnd(picid) (Thanks to a post by SuperRod in this forum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Rnd Function* help topic says *"Before calling Rnd, use the Randomize statement without an argument to initialize the random-number generator with a seed based on the system timer."*

```vb
Randomize
myrand = Int((7 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
```

Comment: That worked great using the first technique but didn't work with the second one. But that's good enough for me. Thanks!